# Trying to log exceptions to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to log crashes in my iPhone app by catching all unhandled exceptions and writing the details to the NSUserDefaults. I set it up by adding this to

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

and defined the function to handle it like this:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {

NSMutableString *errorString = [NSMutableString new];
[errorString appendFormat:@"Exception Name : %@\n", exception.name];
[errorString appendFormat:@"Exception Reason : %@\n", exception.reason];
[errorString appendString:@"User Info : \n"];

for (NSString *key in [[exception userInfo] allKeys]) {
    [errorString appendFormat:@"Key : %@ Value : %@\n", key, [[exception userInfo] valueForKey: key]];
}

[errorString appendFormat:@"Call Stack : %@\n", [exception callStackSymbols]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:errorString forKey:@"ErrorLog"];

NSLog(@"Exception : %@", errorString);
```

}

Everything works fine as far as the function being called when there's a crash and the NSLogs print out all the exception details, but nothing ever gets added to the NSUserDefaults, and I have no idea why.

Does anyone have any idea why this wouldn't set an object into the NSUserDefaults?

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line after you set the object

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:errorString forKey:@"ErrorLog"];
////add this line//////
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
///////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call '`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`'

By the way, how come do you want to use 'NSUserDefaults'?

While developing, you can see log in console.
However, if your App has been released once, crash log in user's device is unreachable so it's useless.

What about using logging service like Flurry or Google analytics?

Comment: The synchronize is what I was forgetting. To answer your question, when the app launches, I check if there is a value in the NSUserDefaults, and if so, I log it to our server, then delete it.

Comment: oh I see. what if user doesn't run the app again after the crash? You know, the logging services I mentioned include realtime crash report too.